# Reducing number of nodes in polygons using Python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, nodes, polygon, level-of-detail

I have a shapefile with several contiguous polygons and I want to reduce their number of nodes keeping the adjacent polygons topologically consistent. 
I was thinking of deleting nodes based on the angle that results from the 2 segments on either side of the node; in particular deleting nodes which form angles <180º and >175º.

I have seen a comment referring to the same idea, but I have very basic knowledge of coding. How could this be implemented in Python?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624475/8435715

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your code snippet.

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm or for the actual code? Imho you have defined your algorithm already and SO is not a code writing service. So I don't understand, what your question is.

Comment: I understand, sorry, I'm not familiar with this forum and I have a too basic knowledge of coding to implement my algorithm. I'll ask again when if i can manage to write the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do that based on two criteria - distance between vertices and the angle you described above:

```
import numpy as np
def reduce_polygon(polygon, angle_th=0, distance_th=0):

    angle_th_rad = np.deg2rad(angle_th)
    points_removed = [0]
    while len(points_removed):
        points_removed = list()
        for i in range(0, len(polygon)-2, 2):
            v01 = polygon[i-1] - polygon[i]
            v12 = polygon[i] - polygon[i+1]
            d01 = np.linalg.norm(v01)
            d12 = np.linalg.norm(v12)
            if d01 < distance_th and d12 < distance_th:
                points_removed.append(i)
                continue
            angle = np.arccos(np.sum(v01*v12) / (d01 * d12))
                if angle < angle_th_rad:
                    points_removed.append(i)
        polygon = np.delete(polygon, points_removed, axis=0)
    return polygon
```

example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from time import time
tic = time()
reduced_polygon = reduce_polygon(original_polygon, angle_th=5, distance_th=4)
toc = time()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(original_polygon[:, 0], original_polygon[:, 1], c='r', marker='o', s=2)
plt.scatter(reduced_polygon[:, 0], reduced_polygon[:, 1], c='b', marker='x', s=20)
plt.plot(reduced_polygon[:, 0], reduced_polygon[:, 1], c='black', linewidth=1)
plt.show()

print(f'original_polygon length: {len(original_polygon)}\n', 
      f'reduced_polygon length: {len(reduced_polygon)}\n'
      f'running time: {round(toc - tic, 4)} secends')
```

Produces the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are the datatype of the polygon in the function?
Could you provide an example? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np

def reduce_polygon(polygon, angle_th=0, distance_th=0):
    angle_th_rad = np.deg2rad(angle_th)
    points_removed = [0]
    while len(points_removed):
        points_removed = list()
        for i in range(0, len(polygon)-2, 2):
            v01 = polygon[i-1] - polygon[i]
            v12 = polygon[i] - polygon[i+1]
            d01 = np.linalg.norm(v01)
            d12 = np.linalg.norm(v12)
            if d01 < distance_th and d12 < distance_th:
                points_removed.append(i)
                continue
            angle = np.arccos(np.sum(v01*v12) / (d01 * d12))
                if angle < angle_th_rad:
                    points_removed.append(i)
        polygon = np.delete(polygon, points_removed, axis=0)
    return polygon
```

Answer (score 0):

Now its working fine!

```
import numpy as np

# Polygon reduction function
def reduce_polygon(polygon_coords, angle_th=0, distance_th=0):
    angle_th_rad = np.deg2rad(angle_th)
    points_removed = [0]
    
    # convert the polygon coordinates into a NumPy array
    polygon = np.array(polygon_coords)
    
    while len(points_removed):
        points_removed = list()
        for i in range(0, len(polygon) - 2, 2):
            v01 = polygon[i - 1] - polygon[i]
            v12 = polygon[i] - polygon[i + 1]
            d01 = np.linalg.norm(v01)
            d12 = np.linalg.norm(v12)
            if d01 < distance_th and d12 < distance_th:
                points_removed.append(i)
                continue
            if d01 * d12 != 0:
                x = np.sum(v01 * v12) / (d01 * d12)
                if np.abs(x) <= 1:
                    angle = np.arccos(x)
                    if angle < angle_th_rad:
                        points_removed.append(i)
        polygon = np.delete(polygon, points_removed, axis=0)
    
    # Convert the reduced polygon back to a list
    reduced_polygon = polygon.tolist()
    
    return reduced_polygon
```